# FieldMask update method implementation

Tags: java, kotlin, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm implementing an API that uses an [update_mask](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/standard_fields) of type [Field Mask](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/field_mask.proto) to specify the fields that should be updated on a resource.

The API is similar to:

```proto
rpc UpdateBook(UpdateBookRequest) returns (Book)
message UpdateBookRequest {
    Book book=1;
    google.protobuf.FieldMask update_mask = 2;
}
```

Currently the code looks something like:

```
override suspend fun updateBook(request: UpdateBookRequest): Book {
    if (!FieldMaskUtil.isValid(Book::class.java, request.updateMask)) {
        throwStatusRuntimeException {
            code = Code.INVALID_ARGUMENT_VALUE
            message = "Invalid field mask"
        }
    }

    request.book.let { book ->
        request.updateMask.pathsList.let { updateMask ->
            var displayName: BookDisplayNameValue? = null
            var description: BookDescriptionValue? = null

            if (updateMask.contains(BookFields.DISPLAY_NAME_FIELD)) {
                displayName = BookDisplayNameValue(book.displayName)
            }
            if (updateMask.contains(BookFields.DESCRIPTION_FIELD)) {
                description = BookDescriptionValue(book.description.ifBlank { null })
            }

            bookService.update(
                    bookId = BookIdValue(book.name),
                    displayName = displayName,
                    description = description,
            )
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Which, although it works, is pretty horrendous for maintenance as more fields are added.

Are there any best practices as to how to implement this behaviour on the server (Kotlin + Spring framework + GRPC) that can reduce the amount of boilerplate.

Comment: Yeah, field masks are pretty horrible... Take a look at `FieldMaskUtil`, but that's as good as it gets https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/FieldMaskUtil

Comment: `FieldMaskUtil` seems handy on the client side. I haven't seen how it can help on the server side.

Comment: I'm thinking `merge()` method. Construct a proto with defaults, and merge in the incoming proto. For updates, instead of passing in nulls, you could 1. Start transaction, 2. Read proto from storage, 3. Merge in request proto with field mask in mind, 4. Write that, 5. Commit transaction